# instantiating a domain object from form input

Tags: webforms, domain-driven-design

In DDD, your domain object's properties are mostly readonly from the outside. Now, in MVC, you'll typically get the object provided to you from the view or repository, but how do you go about this in Webforms, where you read the form inputs manually and apply them to the domain object? Do you create a DTO and give the domain object a Create method that takes the DTO?

Answer (score 1):

> Do you create a DTO and give the domain object a Create method that takes the DTO?

No, you will typically have a piece in the middle, a message handler which is responsible for taking the DTO and converting it to values recognized by the domain.  The domain objects have command methods that are used to update the state of the model.

So something like

1. Receive the DTO
2. Lookup the appropriate handler for that DTO
3. Parse the DTO, creating the value types recognized by the domain
4. Load the target aggregate from the repository
5. Invoke the command on the target, passing domain value types as arguments.

"Input validation" typically happens in step 3.  "Business validation" typically happens on step 5.

Comment: so you'd do your validation / transformation on the DTO, then pass it to the aggregate to instantiate it from the DTO?

Comment: The aggregate never interacts with the DTO.

Comment: Btw, what @VoiceOfUnreason describes (3-5) is an _application service_ in DDD. The DTO is the command sent by the controller that will be handled by the app service

Comment: -1 This answer uses CQRS specific wording while stating that it is typical of DDD. Sorry but this isn't vanilla DDD. Also, the layer that parses the input is *not* an anti-corruption layer.

Comment: I'm not sure the OP was asking about modification of an existing aggregate, I think it was more about creation.

Comment: You're right, I've been misusing "anti-corruption layer".

Answer (score 1):

The common pattern for recording an action or activity in a domain model, is to model the action as an object associated with the thing, people and places it interacts with.

So by example, if one had Orders associated with a Product, one would typically create the Order via an Order method on the applicable product.  Data representing the Order captured via the UI would be passed to that Order method.

[image: Product-Orders]

This represents the simple case for illustration purposes.

Comment: so, in other words, something like
    var childDTO = ChildFromFormInputs();
    //validation or whatever else
    parent.CreateChild(childDTO); Presumably, the parent would pass that dto into the child's constructor for instantiation?

Comment: In my simple example, the data representing the Order captured from the UI is passed as a parameter to the Order() method.  That Order method creates the Order, taking into account any constraints (business rules) for both the Product and the Order.  Business rules are domain concepts, after all only the domain knows about the concepts your problem represents.  That's not to say that the UI can't have applicable "validation" also.  Just realize that conceptually, it is optional.

Answer (score 0):

A good approach is to make your domain entities always valid, always consistent. How you make them consistent right from creation is simply through the entity's constructor or a Factory that will check that the provided input is good enough to construct a valid entity.

> Do you create a DTO and give the domain object a Create method that
>   takes the DTO?

The Domain layer doesn't have a dependency to other layers, so you can't reference an external DTO there. Entity constructors and Factories typically take primitive values or value objects (sometimes other entities) as an input, not DTO's.

Comment: I was thinking of the DTO as a grouping of the properties. So, if you're instantiating from a factory and the properties of the domain are readonly, where would you go about instantiating it? Sure, you could probably use reflection or or something like automapper, but my guess is that the domain entity itself would do the actual moving of the input into its properties, correct?

Comment: The only "grouping of properties" that can be declared in the domain layer are ones that make sense as a business concept and are part of your domain's ubiquitous language. Normally the domain is no place for technical bags of things that are here just for convenience of manipulation.

Comment: But, as far as the instantiation, is my understanding correct?

Comment: Regarding the Factory, if you nest it inside the Entity class, it should be able to manipulate its private fields and private constructor. However, I only use Factories when constructing the object requires complex assemblage logic that deserves its own class. 95% of the time I go with a regular constructor.